# Is it possible to run task with loop async?

Tags: ansible

I have a huge ansible playbook and I have a task, which is using an array (from values) and run the same command for each element in array.

For example (this is just example, I know that I can use one line command!):

```
packages:
  vim:
    dev:
      version: x.x
    qa:
      version: x.x
  redis:
    dev:
      version: x.x
    qa:
      version: x.x
  ...
```

And I have a task which is installing these packages:

```
- name: Install Packages
  include_tasks: tasks/install-packages.yml
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', packages) }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
```

and

```
- name: "Install {{ item.key }} package"
  command: >
    apt-get install {{ item.key }} ...
  environment:
    ...
  retries: 3
  delay: 5
  register: result
  until: result.rc == 0
```

My question is - is it possible to run the last step in threads?

As I understand - first of all I need to split `packages` array and run task in async mode.

In this example - `apt-get install vim` and `apt-get install redis` should start installing simultaneously.

Is it possible? Or maybe there can be some another solution?

The main goal of it - speed up package installation (for this example).

Comment: This is a bad example, because the correct way to speed up package installation is to pass a list of packages to the appropriate module. In fact, trying to parallelize package installation may simply fail. Why not update this to show what you're actually doing? With respect to using `async` mode...try it! See if it does what you want. [This](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) is the place to start, but [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3860/is-there-a-way-to-run-with-items-loops-in-parallel-in-ansible) is probably of itnerest.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I found solution - http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~kauffman/brocade/icx/ansible_modules/user_guide/playbooks_async.html

Answer (score 1):

I found solution [here](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Ekauffman/brocade/icx/ansible_modules/user_guide/playbooks_async.html)

```
#####################
# main.yml
#####################
- name: Run items asynchronously in batch of two items
  vars:
    sleep_durations:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
      - 4
      - 5
    durations: "{{ item }}"
   include_tasks: execute_batch.yml
   loop: "{{ sleep_durations | batch(2) | list }}"

#####################
# execute_batch.yml
#####################
- name: Async sleeping for batched_items
  ansible.builtin.command: sleep {{ async_item }}
  async: 45
  poll: 0
  loop: "{{ durations }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: "async_item"
  register: async_results

- name: Check sync status
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ async_result_item.ansible_job_id }}"
  loop: "{{ async_results.results }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: "async_result_item"
  register: async_poll_results
  until: async_poll_results.finished
  retries: 30
```